# Combine arrays with the same id

Tags: php, sql, arrays, sorting, loops

I am getting data from my database. I have two tables that are relational tables. I am using sql JOIN to get the information needed. Now i have multiple arrays with data in them. But now i would like to combine arrays with the same ID(team_id) and then echo it on the page. Or i mean combine arrays with the same ID(team_id) that i can sort them correctly for each team.

Here is my array that comes from my database. there is can be an infinite number of team names(arrays).

```
Array
(
    [points_1] => 2
    [0] => 2
    [points_2] => 10
    [1] => 10
    [name] => Team 1
    [2] => Team 1
    [team_id] => 1
    [3] => 1
)
Array
(
    [points_1] => 7
    [0] => 7
    [points_2] => 10
    [1] => 10
    [name] => Team 1
    [2] => Team 1
    [team_id] => 1
    [3] => 1
)
Array
(
    [points_1] => 10
    [0] => 10
    [points_2] => 10
    [1] => 10
    [name] => Team 1
    [2] => Team 1
    [team_id] => 1
    [3] => 1
)
Array
(
    [points_1] => 4
    [0] => 4
    [points_2] => 15
    [1] => 15
    [name] => Team 1
    [2] => Team 1
    [team_id] => 1
    [3] => 1
)
Array
(
    [points_1] => 14
    [0] => 14
    [points_2] => 14
    [1] => 14
    [name] => Team 1
    [2] => Team 1
    [team_id] => 1
    [3] => 1
)
Array
(
    [points_1] => 22
    [0] => 22
    [points_2] => 22
    [1] => 22
    [name] => Team 1
    [2] => Team 1
    [team_id] => 1
    [3] => 1
)
Array
(
    [points_1] => 1
    [0] => 1
    [points_2] => 10
    [1] => 10
    [name] => Team 2
    [2] => Team 2
    [team_id] => 3
    [3] => 3
)
Array
(
    [points_1] => 10
    [0] => 10
    [points_2] => 10
    [1] => 10
    [name] => Team 3
    [2] => Team 3
    [team_id] => 6
    [3] => 6
)
```

Here is my Foreach / JOIN code:

```
echo "<pre>";
    foreach ($db->query("SELECT points_1, points_2, name, team_id FROM points INNER JOIN teams ON teams.id=points.team_id ORDER BY team_id ASC") as $result) {
        print_r($result);

    }
```

I would like go through all the arrays and echo them neatly and sorted like in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you output is like this array(you can set the keys you need)

```
$arr = array(
array('name' => 'Team 1','points_1' => 2,'points_2' => 10),
array('name' => 'Team 1','points_1' => 7,'points_2' => 10),
array('name' => 'Team 2','points_1' => 1,'points_2' => 12),
array('name' => 'Team 3','points_1' => 4,'points_2' => 32),
array('name' => 'Team 2','points_1' => 1,'points_2' => 16),
);
```

then try:

```
$arrayTotals = array();


foreach ($arr as $result) {
        //print_r($result);

        $arrayTotals[$result['name']][] = array('points_1'=>$result['points_1'],'points_2'=>$result['points_2']);

}

var_dump($arrayTotals);

foreach($arrayTotals as $team=>$values){
    echo '<div style="float:left;">'.$team;
    $sum1=0;
    $sum2=0;
    foreach($values as $v){
        echo '<br />'.$v['points_1'].'/'.$v['points_2'];
        $sum1 +=$v['points_1'];
        $sum2 +=$v['points_2'];
    }
    echo '<br />Total:'.$sum1.'/'.$sum2;
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I am getting an array of 0: ``array(0) {
}``